# Where should i store credentials and how get them back?

Tags: java

i'm developping a web application in java. During develop of email sender i have to specify credentials (email and password) of my host.

i was doing something like this:

```
public void sendEmail(String toAddress,
        String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {

    // sets SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtp.gmail.com);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    final String username = "user_mail";
    final String password = "password_mail";

    // creates a new session with an authenticator
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    // set plain text message
    msg.setText(message);

    // sends the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg);

}
```

i think that the better practice to use credentials is to save them in an xml file, and calling them back using some method, maybe Context's method.

Can someone explain me (or give me some link where i can see) how can i do that or some better?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The important thing to understand: you have to put in **reasonable** precautions to prevent that people breaking into your host can retrieve that information. So, just storing id + password as plain text within XML is ... **not** a reasonable approach. But honestly, I think your question is way too broad. As there are many many different ways to resolve this. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23489/practices-for-storing-username-password-in-web-applications for example.

Comment: You should really research securing web applications, never save passwords in plaintext. Best practice is to store credentials in a secure database and hash the passwords using a modern hashing algorithm (one that uses a salt).

Comment: one simple way is that use property file for id, password in encrypt mode using security algorithams

Comment: @wybourn that's valid for user credentials, where you want to validate them, but never retriev them, In this case Marco needs the cleartext password for an external service (smtp)

Comment: I see, in that case Vault or Consul would probably be your best option.

Answer (score 2):

One interesting way to do it is to use [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/). It's a system for managing "secrets" like credentials, API keys, etc.

There are other things you can do like write some code to automatically encrypt and decrypt the password.

As a rule of thumb, it's also important to make sure that you don't install the JDK on a production machine. If you do, a hacker would get access to `javap` which is the Java disassembler. The output wouldn't be that good, but probably enough to get a ballpark idea of the method you are using to secure the password.

Comment: And you have to store the Vault credentials somewhere as well. But - indeed if the policies require to change the passwords/key regularily, this seems to be a nice way to keep the credentials current and securely shared..

Comment: Would you like to explain your `JDK/javap` (on ProdMachine), rule of thumb? I don't get it. When a hacker gains access to my server, he could do many things....also just copy the files to another machine (where he also could use `javap`). Older versions of tomcat (for example) requires an installed JDK.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how much effort you want to place in the hiding the secrets. At the end - you have to store the credentials somewhere. You can encrypt them, but you have to store the encryption key somewhere anyway.

Many (even mature) systems simply store the username / password as plains in a configuration file and rely on the hosting to make the system secure. Some systems encrypt the passwords, but the encryption key is available anyway somewhere in a confguration and keystore. It makes retrieving your email password a little bit more complex, but not much.

The most secure way I've seen was creating a key based on a configured secret (password) and some environment property (IP, MAC, ...).

So - lets be practical. Storing your SYSTEM credentials as plains in most of the cases may be ok. You have to secure access to your system so there should be no way to get the configuration file.

Comment: Ask Yahoo what they think about storing passwords as plain text. In my opinion, storing passwords as plain text is a **full stop no go** in 2016. IDs + passwords are **extremely** valuable, and you telling your users "sorry, your data has been **stolen**" is one of the worst things that can happen to you. Your suggestion is like like telling people to **not** put the jewelry into the safe ... you know, because the front door should be locked anyway.

Comment: Besides: if you really know about **mature** systems that do that; please share that knowledge with us. As I would be very much interested in not using any service doing something like that.

Comment: @GhostCat what goes for user (registered user credentials), I fully agree with you. User password should be not recoverable anyway (so - salted strong hash must be used.. at least.). IMHO best option for users should be using multi-factor authentication. Here the problem is otherwise. The credentials are for a SYSTEM account for an external service (email)

Comment: OK. I kinda overlooked that part.